# very simple ajax query not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, post

i know i'm new to ajax but i've been trying this query since around 2 hours straight.

The website i'm trying to connect to is 
http://cbsserver.zni.in/dnd/?phone=xxxxxxxxxx&apikey=xyz 
in this we have to post an private api key which i do have and a mobile phone number to check the status.. To test it please use `phone = '9999052908' & '9810241604'` and `api_key = 'c115da3fcad11daa26dbbfd4f06387d8'` 
the code i'm using is as follows

JQUERY

```
var dnd_api_key = c115da3fcad11daa26dbbfd4f06387d8
    $('input#check_for_dnd').click(function() {
                $.post("http://cbsserver.zni.in/dnd/",
            {
            phone:"9999052908",
            apikey: dnd_api_key
            },
      function(data,status){
        alert(status + "data:" + data);
      });
```

HTML

```
<input type="button" id="check_for_dnd" name="check_for_dnd" value="CHECK DND STATUS" />
```

please tell me where i'm going wrong..

Comment: Does the api support CORS? (the fact that it fails probably means that it doesn't support CORS) otherwise this isnt possible, you'll have to make the request from your server.

Comment: ajax calls can only be made back to the server from which the javascript was loaded from. The only other method of doing this is via JSONP calls, if that api supports such things.

Comment: "Not working" is a very poor description of your problem.  What precise error is occurring?

Comment: You should edit out your api key for obvious reasons soonish.

Comment: not working here means the alert does not pop up... Sorry for being such a noob

Comment: how to know the api supports CORS or not?? @KevinB

Comment: @user1817626 It will return a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header

Comment: the link http://cbsserver.zni.in/dnd/?phone=9711087459&apikey=c115da3fcad11daa26dbbfd4f06387d8
returns the following headers
HTTP/1.1 200 OK => 
Connection => close
Date => Wed, 14 Nov 2012 18:58:40 GMT
Server => Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By => ASP.NET
Content-Length => 1
Content-Type => text/html
Set-Cookie => ASPSESSIONIDCQRCCDRR=MIPMGJEBLEFLCJBIHPPDIAIL; path=/
Cache-control => private

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not - generally speaking and without exceptions like JSONP and CORS - make ajax calls to remote urls.

Try using a "proxy file" on your server that requests the page (e.g. written in PHP). Then make an ajax call to this proxy file which is located at your server.

This could look like this (if the service is also fine with GET-requests, otherwise you have to use streams or CURL):

```
$result = file_get_contents("http://cbsserver.zni.in/dnd/?phone=xxxxxxxxxx&apikey=xyz");
echo $result;
```

Save this file on your server and request it with ajax like you would:

```
$('input#check_for_dnd').click(function() {
                $.post("my_proxy_file.php",
      function(data,status){
        alert(status + "data:" + data);
      });
```

Comment: please elaborate a bit more.. then i'll try to search about proxy files ... never used them..

Comment: i've found http://www.abdulqabiz.com/blog/archives/2007/05/31/php-proxy-script-for-cross-domain-requests/ . but doesnt help.. since script is not downloadable.. @David Müller

Comment: Updated my post with an example. "Proxy file" was just a term for a php script handling the request for you.

Comment: I think you're looking at a REST service.  Here is some basic information on REST: http://phpwebservices.blogspot.ca/2008/01/rest-with-php_20.html

as David Muller said, you can use this code in your "Proxy File"...but don't google Proxy File...david just made that term up

Comment: actually the above mentioned website is a developer's api, so it must support CORS...
@David Muller

Comment: You know what CORS is, right? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: read about it .. and now i understand that this website does not allow resource sharing.. I shall now try to look into the other option. 'proxy file' method... Please share any tutorial if you have... thanks

Comment: You don't need anything else despite the code I already included in my updated post. Just add your api key and there you go. Don't get too mad about my terminology of "proxy file" which I made up, as Kubee already said ;).

Comment: @DavidMüller file_get_contents worked perfectly. Can i not use `$.get("http://cbsserver.zni.in/dnd/?phone=9999052908&apikey=c115da3fcad11daa26dbbfd4f06387d8",function(data){$('#a_textbox').val(data)});` .. is get() not equivalent of file_get_content for jquery...

Comment: @DavidMüller Sir , so is there any way in which i could send a jquery request and do it on the fly... ??

Comment: Please carefully read my post, I already explained everything. `file_get_contents` by a script on your server and you requesting this script via `$.get`.